# AttributeError in pydantic while assigning value in class

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, fastapi, pydantic

I have two different pydantic BaseModel class in to different file.
in X.py I have:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class somefirst(BaseModel):
      flag: bool = False
```

in Y.py I have:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class somesecond(BaseModel):
      flagvalue: bool = False
```

what I want to do in Y.py is:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from X import somefirst

class somesecond(BaseModel):
      flagvalue: somefirst.flag
```

**I am getting AttributeError saying type obj somefirst has no attribute "flag"**

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to use the default value that would be used for any instance of `somefirst`?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are initialized when you create an object of of the class. So you could do something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class somefirst(BaseModel):
      flag: bool = False


class somesecond(BaseModel):
      flagvalue: somefirst().flag
```

But is it really needed that in `somesecond` the name of the attribute changes? If what you want is to extend a Model by attributes of another model I recommend using inheritance:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SomeFirst(BaseModel):
      flag: bool = False


class SomeSecond(SomeFirst):
      pass


second = SomeSecond()
print(second.flag)  # output: False
```

Comment: There are other attributes in each class. I want to take only the attribute with boolean. @finswimmer